# How do I make a custom printable bullet point to use in MS Office?

Tags: microsoft-office, adobe-photoshop, cutepdf

I'd like to make a custom bullet point on Photoshop (I'm moderately experienced at it) styled like the asterisk symbol for use with MS Office. I tried using just an image selection to make a 12x12 GIF file. It works just fine on on-screen stuff (looks perfectly fine, no pixelation).

When I try to print to PDF however (using CutePDF), the custom bullets I created appear pixelated. I was wondering if there was any way to get around this or is it just the fact that asterisk signs have non-perpendicular lines which are just bound to get pixelated? or could this be what I'm using for PDF conversion?

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

i'd guess its cause standard fonts are vectors, and those gifs are raster images and are being resized badly. The solution might be to recreate those gifs as fonts with something like [fontforge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/).

considering cutepdf uses ghostscript (which is the default FOSS postscript engine), i doubt its cutepdf doing something odd.